# Mutually Exclusive Property across items in a Collection

Tags: mvvm, caliburn.micro

[image: Screenshot]

I have simplified this considerably, however I have a question as to this best way to tackle this problem.

In the attached screenshot, I have the requirement that there can only be one Primary Contact.  The user should be able to change the Primary Contact either from the List View (the left side of the screen shot) or the Detail View (the right side of the screen shot).

In other words, if the user were to check Jane Doe in the List View, the checkbox next to John Smith would be deselected.  The same would occur in the Detail view, if the checkbox for Jane Doe would be checked, John Smith would be deselected.

I am using Caliburn.Micro for my MVVM framework, and have attached the sample project.

I tried to make the project very simple.  I did not solve the problem in the attached project, I am hoping to get different ideas on how to solve it.

[WpfApplication1.zip](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0Bx_O1D_19kS-aWN1YWMtdWNDT2M)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the business objects responsibility to determine what happens to the other items should one become primary, therefore you need some sort of object which manages the `IsPrimary` flag.

However you do it (custom container type, mediator etc) you need something to mediate the changes

e.g.

```
public class Mediator
{
    IList<Contact> _contacts = null;

    public Mediator(IList<Contact> contacts) 
    {
        _contacts = contacts;

        foreach(var c in contacts) 
        {
            c.PropertyChanged += ContactPropertyChanged;
        }
    }

    private bool _isChanging = false;

    private void ContactPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var current = sender as Contact;

        if(e.PropertyName == "IsPrimary" && !_isChanging && current.IsPrimary)
        {
            _isChanging = true;

            foreach(var c in _contacts.Where(x => x != current) 
            {
                c.IsPrimary = false;
            }

            _isChanging = false;
        }
    }
}
```

There are probably better ways, like having a container collection (which hooks the propertychanged etc on it's own ... also watch out for the event handlers!)

You could write a more generic templated version which fires an overload (so you can easily just subclass to create different mediators etc)

```
public class Mediator<T>
{
    IList<T> _items = null;

    public Mediator(IList<T> items, params string[] watchedProperties) { ... etc

    protected virtual OnWatchedPropertyChanged(T sender, string PropertyName) 
    {
    }
}

public ContactMediator : Mediator<Contact>
{
     public ContactMediator(IList<Contact> contacts, params string[] watchedProperties) { ...

     override OnWatchedPropertyChanged(Contact object, string propertyName) { ... etc
}
```

Comment: In my real application, I already had a Collection Class (i.e. ContractCollection) which was managing this requirement.  I however chose a very complicated approach :).  I like this approach much better.  Thanks for the assist!

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, there are a couple of basic options.  The direction I would go would be to create a Model object called Person and have a boolean property called IsPrimary.  I would have this model object implement INotifyPropertyChanged.  In my ViewModel object, I would have a BindingList collection object of Person objects.  Then wire up some commands for the checkboxes to trigger changes in the Person object, and that should do it.

Comment: Sure, I have that already in the Solution I have attached to the original question.  The complication is ensuring that there is only ever one Primary Contact.